# Implement a Caption Property in a Model Entity?

Tags: c#, metadata, caption

Recently we are converting `Datatable` to `List` of Models.. 
I had a class called `Person` ( `personid` ,`PersonChildId`} and I implemented my class as

```
public class Person 
{
    public Int64 PerosnId{ get; set; }
    public Int64 PersonChildID{ get; set; }
}
```

I sucessfully converted my `Datatable` to `List<Person>` by using simple for loop. But now the problem is as we know `Datacolumn` has a property called `Caption`. but unfortunately models don't have.
 So how do we need implement a Caption property for the Model for these kind of scenarios.

Comment: By adding a `Caption` property?!

Comment: Caption Property for entire Person class ? If we treat PersonId and PersonChildId as two different columns these both need a different caption... so how do we handle this

Comment: Oh...Why Down Vote ..,. whats wrong in this question yaar?

Comment: Ohhh, now I see what you meant, see my answer below.

Comment: Do you still have problems?

Comment: Hi gdoron, i understood that i cannot use custom attributes in my scenario, because i need to access my attributes from WCF server to client. but as per my knowledge (google :)) custom attributes cannot be transferred in SOAP. so do we have any alternative for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an attribute like the [`DisplayName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.aspx):

```
public class Person 
{
    [DisplayName("Person ID:"]
    public Int64 PerosnId{ get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Person Child ID:"]
    public Int64 PersonChildID{ get; set; }
}
```

You can get the value of the attribute with:

```
var caption = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true)
      .Cast<DisplayNameAttribute>.Single().DisplayName;
```

Comment: Can we set the Attribute at runtime?

Comment: @Bhuvan, Yes, it's possible.

Comment: hi gdoron , ok but how do we access the display name. For example if we want to access PersonID we can use it as objPerson.PersonId... in the same way how do we access display name of the personId in code

Comment: @gdoron.. Hi .. i am not getting the value of the attribute when i am trying to retreive it at client side as " Person objPerson = new Person();

            var caption = objPerson.GetType().GetProperty("PersonId").GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true).Cast<DisplayNameAttribute>().Single().DisplayName;".. Could you please suggest me whether i am in a correct approach to access the Displayname from client

Comment: now i understood.. in a WCF service i am able to access the attribute at server side.. but i am not able to access the attribute at client side.. how do we need to access the attribute at client side

Comment: @Bhuvan: Add a new web service method: `GetCaptionsForModel` which you invoke with `"Person"` as argument. Save it client side so that you only have to retrieve it once.

Comment: ok.. you are saying to implement in my server as GetCaptionsForModel(Person objPerson) at server side.. and you want me to access the same method in the client side. But how do i send the DisplayNames here..?

Comment: @Bhuvan, This thread became too messy, try asking another question with the new data you found. One question for a thread is the policy here, and it's a good policy.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Full_Name:")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public string Adress { get; set; }

    public string SSID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Mr. Mohammad, consider adding more info how your code might solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!